# PowerApps: Patching to a Second SharePoint List with Secondary Button

Tags: powerapps, sharepoint-list, powerapps-formula

**My Overall Goal:**
I am trying to Patch "Notes" to my SharePoint List Lead_History.

**My Process:**
I have a main SharePoint list that contains all my Lead Data called Lead_Data but this list excludes my Lead_History (or notes) as there can be multiple entries per lead for this. 
I have a dashboard page that I click to display the Specfic Lead data which has a list at the bottom of all the history of notes. I want to be able from this same screen to be able to add to my history of notes.
I have added a textbox and I want to be able to patch this box by clicking on the + button rather than the checkmark in my top right corner. I want the user to see that the item is added to the gallery at the bottom of the screen.

**The current code I have, that is not working is:**

```
Patch(Lead_History, Lead_History.LeadID = Gallery_Dashboard.Selected.ID, {Note: txt_HistoryDetail.Text, HistoryDate: Text( Now(), "[$-en-US]mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")});
```

It just keeps telling me there is an invalid argument but I have no idea what I am doing wrong. In my mind this should do what I want.

Is anyone able to help me figure this out? I have a screen cap below to visualize what I am saying above.

[Screen capture of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spUDG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work through this with someone very kind and patient in another online community. Here is the answer in case anyone else tries to do the same or similar.

`Patch(Lead_History, Defaults(Lead_History), {Title: "", Note: txt_HistoryDetail.Text, HistoryDate: Text( Now(), "[$-en-US]mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), LeadID: Gallery_Dashboard.Selected.ID});`